# Magic 8 Ball Program Looping Not Working As Expected

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on this Magic 8 Ball assignment for my class, and I am having some issues with the final part of the assignment.

The original code was this:

```
import random
import time

question = input('What is your question? ')

if 'Why?' in question or 'Why' in question or 'why' in question:
   print('Why not?')
else:
   randomResponse = random.randint(1,4)
   if randomResponse == 1:
       print('...the probabilities are in your favor...')
   if randomResponse == 2:
       print('...make no definite plans...')
   if randomResponse == 3:
       print('...the answer is hazy...')
   if randomResponse == 4:
       print('...you already know the answer...')
```

The assignment is basically to do this:

1) As is, the code only asks for one question and provides an answer. Alter the code so that it contains a loop to keep asking questions and providing answers until the user has no more questions.

2) The only key word the program looks for in the user's question is 'Why'. Alter the program so it checks for at least three more keywords and provides answers specific to that key word.

3) Modify the code so the generic answers are determined in a function, The header for the function is def generalResponse(question):

I've gotten #1 and #2 to work, but #3 is giving me a little bit of a headache since I cannot seem to get my program to escape out of the while loop when I create a separate function for my general responses.

Here is my code so far:

```
import random
import time

question = input('What is your question?\nIf you are finished asking questions, type "Done".')

def generalResponse(question):  
    question = question
    randomResponse = random.randint(1,4)  
    if question == "Done":
        exit()     
    elif randomResponse == 1:
        print('...the probabilities are in your favor...')
        question = input('What is your next question?\nIf you are finished asking questions, type "Done".')
    elif randomResponse == 2:
        print('...make no definite plans...')
        question = input('What is your next question?\nIf you are finished asking questions, type "Done".')
    elif randomResponse == 3:
        print('...the answer is hazy...')
        question = input('What is your next question?\nIf you are finished asking questions, type "Done".')
    elif randomResponse == 4:
        print('...you already know the answer...')
        question = input('What is your next question?\nIf you are finished asking questions, type "Done".')       


while(question != "Done"):
    if 'Why?' in question or 'Why' in question or 'why' in question:
        print('Why not?')
        question = input('What is next your question?\nIf you are finished asking questions, type "Done".')
    elif 'How?' in question or 'How' in question or 'how' in question:
        print('Leave it to the Universe to figure out how.')
        question = input('What is your next question?\nIf you are finished asking questions, type "Done".')
    elif 'Who?' in question or 'Who' in question or 'who' in question:
        print('Who are you?')
        question = input('What is your next question?\nIf you are finished asking questions, type "Done".') 
    elif 'Where?' in question or 'Where' in question or 'where'in question:
        print('Sorry, I am not a GPS.')  
        question = input('What is your next question?\nIf you are finished asking questions, type "Done".')      
    else:
        generalResponse(question)
```

I am not sure where I am quite going wrong with this since I cannot seem to get the program to exit once it's in the general response function, but any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The issue here is variable scope. The 'question' variable in your function is not the referring to the same thing as 'question' in your loop. What you want to do is return a value from the function, and then print it in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is variable scope. When you define a variable in a function, it only has that value within that function, unless you make it global with the 'global' keyword. Therefore, when you enter into the 'generalResponse' function, the value of 'question' in your loop doesn't change, therefore you will be sent back to the 'generalResponse' function again by the loop, repeatedly, and the program won't quit regardless of what you input. To fix this, it is best to make the function just determine the response, and then return it to your loop. As a rule, a function should only ever do one thing. It should't get input, determine an output, and print it (usually). The code below will fix your issue.

```
import random
import time

question = input('What is your question?\nIf you are finished asking questions, type "Done".')

def generalResponse(question):  
    question = question
    randomResponse = random.randint(1,4)  
    if question == "Done":
        exit()     
    elif randomResponse == 1:
        return '...the probabilities are in your favor...'
    elif randomResponse == 2:
        return '...make no definite plans...'
    elif randomResponse == 3:
        return '...the answer is hazy...'
    elif randomResponse == 4:
        return '...you already know the answer...'


while(question != "Done"):
    if 'Why?' in question or 'Why' in question or 'why' in question:
        print('Why not?')
        question = input('What is next your question?\nIf you are finished asking questions, type "Done".')
    elif 'How?' in question or 'How' in question or 'how' in question:
        print('Leave it to the Universe to figure out how.')
        question = input('What is your next question?\nIf you are finished asking questions, type "Done".')
    elif 'Who?' in question or 'Who' in question or 'who' in question:
        print('Who are you?')
        question = input('What is your next question?\nIf you are finished asking questions, type "Done".') 
    elif 'Where?' in question or 'Where' in question or 'where'in question:
        print('Sorry, I am not a GPS.')  
        question = input('What is your next question?\nIf you are finished asking questions, type "Done".')      
    else:
        response = generalResponse(question)
        print(response)
        question = input('What is your next question?\nIf you are finished asking questions, type "Done".')
```

In the code below I've included a much more compact version of that will achieve the same thing. I've included comments inline to explain what each part is doing.

```
import random
import time


# The convention is to use capital letters for constants.
QUESTION = 'What is your question?\nIf you are finished asking questions, type "Done".' # Put this text into a variable so that you only have to type it once.

GENERAL_RESPONSES = [
    '...the probabilities are in your favor...',
    '...make no definite plans...',
    '...the answer is hazy...',
    '...you already know the answer...'
    ] # avoid clutter by keeping your data seperate from the program logic


def generalResponse(question):  
    randomResponse = random.randint(0,3) # we can just get the list index directly 
    return GENERAL_RESPONSES[randomResponse]


while True:
    question = input(QUESTION)
    if question == "Done":
        exit()
    elif 'Why?' in question or 'why'.upper() in question.upper(): # using .upper() let's you do a case insensitive search with one command.
        print("Why not")
    elif "How?" in question or "how".upper() in question.upper():
        print('Leave it to the Universe to figure out how.')
    elif 'Who?' in question or 'who'.upper() in question.upper():
        print('Who are you?')
    elif 'Where?' in question or 'where'.upper() in question.upper():
        print('Sorry, I am not a GPS.')  
    else:
        response = generalResponse(question)
        print(response)
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer was really helpful and got me to understand what the issue with my program was. Really appreciate it!